# urgent!! i want to forecast health expenditure but the data is very small, only have a dataset of 20 samples

Tags: time-series, forecasting

i tried using ARIMA but cannot due to small dataset. anybody know other time series forecasting for small dataset of 20 sample? urgent need help

Comment: Predict the average value every time? With so few data, it will be challenging to develop a reliable model of much more complexity than that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to such small dataset:

1. a good understanding of the underlying processes that generate the data is crucial.
2. Then you need to find a suitable model with very few parameters that you can estimate from the data.
3. The model can be used for extrapolation and forecasting.

**Note:** The quality of the forecast would then strongly depend on the choice of model and how well it fits to the underlying use case.

Comment: do you know any good model?

Comment: I am lacking point 1 in my above list. Without that, I can not give a good recommendation.